# How to customize a image inside a table cell in html?

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I've created a table inside a html page. Then I've inserted a image into a cell. What I want to know is how to edit the size of that image. Please help!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the (formatted) code you've written. It will make it easier for others to help you with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the style attribute to add css to your image, like so:

```
<table>
    <td>
        <img style="height: 10px; width: 10px"/>
    </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the image size and width within the  tag as such

```
<img height="200px" width="200px>
```

As well as other edits such as borders and aligns , you can go more in depth with CSS

Answer (score 0):

In CSS? table > img { height: 1px; width: 1px; }
you can use tr or td instead of table.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the image or scale the parent of the image, the table cell.

The question below has an answer to scale the table cell and fit the image inside.

[Fit image to table cell width percentage (HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860020/fit-image-to-table-cell-width-percentage-html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about how to target the image, then you need to do something like...

```
table tr td img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 25%;
}
```

You are best off using percentages as this will scale responsively better.